# count number of formats in a python string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm reading a buffer from memory containing strings that may contain a number(up to 3) of formats within them(like `%d`, `%x` etc.) I need to know how many formats the string has so I can fetch them and print the string.. Is there any better way to do this but count the `%`'s in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> fmt = '%d, %x, %%'
>>> fmt.count('%')
4
```

To exclude `%%`:

```
>>> fmt.count('%') - fmt.count('%%') * 2
2
```

Comment: yes, that would do.. I was wondering if there was something more elegant built in.. thanks anyway